# Prevent duplicates in MySql without using unique constraint

Tags: mysql, locking, unique-constraint

I have a `rules` table consist of a column called `priority`, that must be gapless, incremental and unique.
A user must be able to re-order priority of the rules. For example, if there are 10 rules for a user and she moves the last rule to the 5th place, all of the other records between must get updated.
To prevent race condition during updates, I can use a `select ... for update` lock. But I can't find a way to guarantee the uniqueness of `priority` during inserts.
Firstly I wanted to use a deferred unique constraint, but figured out that MySql does not support this feature as Postgres do.
Then I thought about using a trigger on before insert, to calculate the priority, but I found that duplications still can show up.
What must I do? Is there any way to create a unique check that only works during inserts not updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` on repeatable read (which is the default isolation level in MySql) [may lead to gap locks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-gap-locks) and poor performance.

If the list you're maintaining has limited items (e.g. ~100 rules for each user),  I suggest to add a column named `version` and hold a unique constraint/index on <priority, version> and then try to mimic eventual consistency. Here's an example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE rules (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    priority INT NOT NULL,
    version INT NOT NULL,
    user_id INT NOT NULL, -- foreign key of user
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE(priority, version)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO rules (priority, version, user_id) VALUES (5,1,0),(4,1,0),(3,1,0),(2,1,0),(1,1,0);
```

To bring up the 4th row (with priority = 2) to the 2nd place (which has priority = 4), you should:

1. Set the priority of the 4th row to 4 and increment version
2. Decrement priority and increment version of the rules with priority between 3 and 4
3. Increment version of the remaining rules

```sql
BEGIN;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('(', priority, ',', version, ')') ORDER BY id) FROM rules WHERE user_id = 0;
-- (5,1),(4,1),(3,1),(2,1),(1,1)

UPDATE rules SET version = version + 1, priority = priority - 1 WHERE user_id = 0 AND version = 1 AND priority BETWEEN 3 AND 4;
-- (5,1),(3,2),(2,2),(2,1),(1,1)

UPDATE rules SET version = version + 1, priority = 4 WHERE user_id = 0 AND version = 1 AND priority = 2;
-- (5,1),(3,2),(2,2),(4,2),(1,1)

UPDATE rules SET version = version + 1 WHERE user_id = 0 AND version = 1 AND priority NOT BETWEEN 2 AND 4;
-- (5,2),(3,2),(2,2),(4,2),(1,2)

COMMIT;
```

This way, all of the rows will eventually have the same version and there will be no duplicate priorities (in that version).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a complete test case, annotated:

```
CREATE TABLE t_rearr (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    priority INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE(priority)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO t_rearr (priority) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);


BEGIN;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY priority) FROM t_rearr FOR UPDATE;  
-- Expect 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10  
-- Note the FOR UPDATE  

-- 3 steps to swap:
-- First, move out of way (this assumes 0 is not a valid priority)
UPDATE t_rearr SET priority =  0 WHERE priority =  5;

UPDATE t_rearr SET priority =  5 WHERE priority = 10;

UPDATE t_rearr SET priority = 10 WHERE priority =  0;

COMMIT;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY priority) FROM t_rearr;
# Expect 1,2,3,4,10,6,7,8,9,5
```